How to log traces in Opentelemetry Collector to stdout
we're using an OTel collector to funnel and sample traces from several microservices. We would like to log those traces (the actual trace) as single-line JSONs, crucially including attributes, to stdout, as we have a built in system to store and scrape such logs.
Is there any built in way to make this happen?
We're aware that there are other kinds of exporters (including a file exporter), but they don't suit our needs.
Thanks for your help
So far we've tried the logging/debug exporter, but the only options seem to be to either log just the fact that some trace arrived (info level in logging exporter, for example) or a prettified, not machine readable full trace:
 ScopeSpans #0
 ScopeSpans SchemaURL:
 InstrumentationScope someservice
 Span #0
     Trace ID       : a4a3ddc377e320136f89d825358cff7f
     Parent ID      : 03ba2cf185f7b7ad
     ID             : 7f46dc9f86ab0e4d
     Name           : http_request
     Kind           : Client
     Start time     : 2024-06-24 09:34:50.968806671 +0000 UTC
     End time       : 2024-06-24 09:34:50.990112034 +0000 UTC
     Status code    : Unset
     Status message :
 Attributes:
      -> thread.name: Str(tokio-runtime-worker)
      -> thread.id: Int(2)
      [...]
 ResourceSpans #13
 Resource SchemaURL:
 Resource attributes:
      -> service.name: Str(somename)
      [...]

Ideally, we would like a single line json with the same information. We tried adding:
services:
  [...]
  telemetry:
    logs:
      encoding: json

In the config file, as suggested in this question, but it only resulted in printing the same thing as a string attribute:
{
  "level": "info",
  "ts": 1719219718.818462,
  "msg": "ResourceSpans #0\nResource SchemaURL: [... very very long line ...]",
  "kind": "exporter",
  "data_type": "traces",
  "name": "logging"
}


This is not the recommended way in opentelemetry, so there isn't anything that does this. You could build an exporter for the collector, or make your custom solution accept OTLP data. Using OTLP is the recommended way.

In case anyone else has a similar setup, we ended up picking the syslog exporter: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/syslogexporter
